# How to Call Functions With Ajax By Clicking Button With Given ID From jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to build website for team project. Basically, this web-site takes some datas from [here](http://sitename.herokuapp.com/api/v1/polls/). I used HTML, PHP, jQuery and Ajax in order to provide some functionalities for my website. I created an object with PHP and I printing functionalities by using for loop. **poll_id** is the critical part in there because when I vote two photos, I use specific ID in order to determine which poll will be voted. [Here is the little snapshot from my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX9vO.png). Let's come to the problem. If I use SESSION in order to pass values to "Ajax.php" which includes post functions to our API, it directly votes last poll element of the database whichever I clicked.

So, question is >>> How can I pull specific ID from jQuery to Ajax by clicking button.

Here the some code to clarify my question.

From Ajax.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//$polls_id = $_SESSION['polls_id'];
if($_GET) {
    if(isset($_GET['insert'])) {
        vote_poll1($user_id, $polls_id);
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['select'])) {
        vote_poll2($user_id, $polls_id);
    }
}

function vote_poll1($user_id, $polls_id){
    $postdata = http_build_query(
                                array(
                                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                                    'poll_id' => $polls_id,
                                    'vote_value' => '1'
                                     )
                                );

    $opts = array(
                'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $postdata
                                )
                 );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = file_get_contents('http://sitename.herokuapp.com/api/v1/polls/'. $polls_id . '/castvote', false, $context);
```

FROM First.php

```
public function getButtons() {
            //$_SESSION['polls_id'] = $this->polls_id;
            //echo $_SESSION['polls_id'];
            echo $this->polls_id;

            echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>';
            echo '<form action="ajax.php" id=' . $this->polls_id . '>';
            echo "\t";
                echo '<input type="submit" class="button" name="insert" value="Click here to vote" />';
                echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t  ";
                echo '<input type="submit" class="button" name="select" value="Click here to vote" />';
            echo "</form>";
            echo "<script>";
                echo "$(document).ready(function(){";
                    echo "$('.button').click(function(){";
                    echo "var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();";
                    echo "var idValue = $(this).attr('id')";
                    echo "var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php'";
                    //echo "var id = " . $this->polls_id;
                    echo "data =  {'action': clickBtnValue, 'id': idValue};";
                    echo "$.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {";
                        echo 'alert("Action performed successfully");';
                    echo "});";
                echo "});";
            echo "});";
            echo "</script>";
        } 
    }
```

How can I take id from my jQuery script code to my Ajax.php in order to send appropriate data to our API?

Comment: It is pretty much [jQuery 101](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html). Also, I would make separate jQuery files which can be included, rather than doing the echo in First.php as that is awfully prone to error.

Comment: Agreed, passing variables through ajax is a pretty basic core concept.  You can do it any number of ways, via `$('#button_target').prop("id");` or passing it with JS function syntax, or any method.  If you are talking about form data, the easiest way is to use something like `var formdata = $('#formtarget').serialize();`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sir, I added $polls_id = $_POST['id']; into my Ajax.php file. Also I deleted "id" tag from <form></form> and add <div id=$this->polls_id></div> just above the <input type="submit"......> line. However, still does not work. Can you share your experience on my code?